# WebStorm fixing all TSLint error is fixing all but one

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, tslint

In WebStorm my `tslint.json` of my Angular project contains following lines

```
"triple-equals": [
  true,
  "allow-null-check"
]
```

and whenever I give `==` comparison in my `component.ts` file, it shows the lint warning, along with other TSLint warnings and errors.

After clicking on "TSLint:Fix current File" it fix all issues but doesn't convert `==` to `===` and keeps displaying the warning that `==` should be `===`.

Please advise how to fix this.

Comment: can you post an example of the code you think it should but doesn't correct   ... i.e. you say `whenever I give == comparison` ...but what are you comparing? without the **code** that is giving you an issue, how do expect help? Do you even know what that configuration does?

Comment: Hey @JaromandaX here is a piece of code, which I expect it to fix but it doesn't:   if (event.type == "submit") { // do something } else { //something else }   so here it displays two issues, first " should be ' and the second is about this ==

Comment: fair enough, because I though you may have been comparing with `null` - without code, there is only speculation :p

Comment: Maybe it's intentional? Automatically converting from `==` to `===` may break logic where there must be loosely comparison `==`. (E.g. `let a = '0';` then `0 == a;` and `0 === a` would give different output

Comment: @Justinas what you said makes sense, but as per the functionality this should work, isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all TSLint rules are fixable, and, in particular, running `tslint --fix` doesn't fix "*triple-equals*" errors. This is done intentionally, I suppose, as, though using the strict equality operator is recommended in most cases, the abstract equality operator is sometimes handy due to its coercion capabilities (when a number comes as a string from ajax call, for example).

Anyway, it's not an issue with WebStorm; if you miss auto-fix for this rule, please feel free to file a request to https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues